# Getting a footer link to the right and lined up with text that is on the left side

Tags: html, css, footer

I have some text on the left side of my footer and i want my links to be on the right but at the same time lined up with my text that is on the left. I tried to float the links to the right but not only are the links not in order, they also don't line up with the text on the left.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gL2xtezz/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Taffies Cupakes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.png" alt="taffies logo"></a>
    </header> <!-- end of header -->

    <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="orders.html">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- end of nav -->

        <div class="company_info">
            <p>Taffies cupcakes</p>
            <p>111 x drive road</p>
            <p>milton keynes</p>
            <p>l0002</p><br>
            <p>telephone: 078 878-8888</p>
        </div> <!-- end of compnay info text -->

</aside> <!-- end of aside -->

<section class="first_article">
    <article>
        <p class="first_main_paragraph">Welcome to Taffies Cupcakes website! In here you will find various types of cupcakes we offer. Our cupcakes are fresh and we deliver in 24 hours. </p>
        <p class="second_main_paragraph">Check out the gallery section to see which type of cupcake you prefer. If you don't see your favorite, you can contact us and give us suggestions on what other type of cupcakes we should offer. We take feedback seriously and want to provide the best cupcakes to our customers.</p>
        <a href="orders.html"><img src="images/contact-button.png" alt="contact_button" class="contact_button"></a>
        <img src="images/cupcake.png" alt="cupcake" class="cupcake">
    </article>
</section> <!-- end of section -->

<footer>
    <p>Taffie's Cupcakes &copy; copyright 2014</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="orders.html">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer> <!-- end of footer -->

</div> <!-- end of container -->
</body> 
</html>



*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

header,nav,section,article,aside,footer{
    display:block;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

body{
    background-color:#e8d4cb;
}

header img{
    padding:43px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.first_article{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.first_main_paragraph{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.second_main_paragraph{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.first_article .contact_button{
    float:left;
    margin-top:165px;
}

.first_article .cupcake{
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:19px;
}

.sidebar{
    float:left;
    margin:30px;
    margin-right:40px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:myriad pro;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#3d2316;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:85px;
    padding-right:29px;
    padding-top:26px;
    padding-bottom:26px;
    width:39%;  
}

nav ul li:hover a{
    color:#e8d5cc;
}

nav ul li{
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background-color: #CBAFA2;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #3D2316;
}

.company_info{
    background-color:#cbafa2;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#3d2316;
    font-family:myriad pro;
}

.about_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.about_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.about_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.orders_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.orders_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.second_order{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.order_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.order_numbers{
    color:#3D2316;
}

.gallery_section{
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    margin:25px;
}

.gallery_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.contact_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.contact_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.contact_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

footer{
    clear:both;
    font-family:arial;
    border-top:1px solid #aa8573;
    height:100px;
}

footer p{
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}

footer ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;

}

footer ul li a:hover{
    color:#3d2316;
}

figure{
    float:left;
    margin:25px;
}

figcaption{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-top:15px;
}

span{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#846a5f;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of `li` and use `float: right` to `footer ul li`

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gL2xtezz/3/)

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

header,nav,section,article,aside,footer{
    display:block;
}

.container{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

body{
    background-color:#e8d4cb;
}

header img{
    padding:43px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.first_article{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.first_main_paragraph{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.second_main_paragraph{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.first_article .contact_button{
    float:left;
    margin-top:165px;
}

.first_article .cupcake{
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:19px;
}

.sidebar{
    float:left;
    margin:30px;
    margin-right:40px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:myriad pro;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#3d2316;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:85px;
    padding-right:29px;
    padding-top:26px;
    padding-bottom:26px;
    width:39%;  
}

nav ul li:hover a{
    color:#e8d5cc;
}

nav ul li{
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background-color: #CBAFA2;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #3D2316;
}

.company_info{
    background-color:#cbafa2;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#3d2316;
    font-family:myriad pro;
}

.about_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.about_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.about_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.orders_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.orders_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.second_order{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.order_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

.order_numbers{
    color:#3D2316;
}

.gallery_section{
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    margin:25px;
}

.gallery_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.contact_section{
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin:25px;
}

.contact_title{
    color:#3d2316;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:30px;
}

.contact_text{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
}

footer{
    clear:both;
    font-family:arial;
    border-top:1px solid #aa8573;
    height:100px;
}

footer p{
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}

footer ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#784f3d;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;

}
footer ul li {
    float: right;
}
footer ul li a:hover{
    color:#3d2316;
}

figure{
    float:left;
    margin:25px;
}

figcaption{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#846a5f;
    margin-top:15px;
}

span{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#846a5f;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Taffies Cupakes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.png" alt="taffies logo"></a>
    </header> <!-- end of header -->

    <aside class="sidebar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="orders.html">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- end of nav -->

        <div class="company_info">
            <p>Taffies cupcakes</p>
            <p>111 x drive road</p>
            <p>milton keynes</p>
            <p>l0002</p><br>
            <p>telephone: 078 878-8888</p>
        </div> <!-- end of compnay info text -->

</aside> <!-- end of aside -->

<section class="first_article">
    <article>
        <p class="first_main_paragraph">Welcome to Taffies Cupcakes website! In here you will find various types of cupcakes we offer. Our cupcakes are fresh and we deliver in 24 hours. </p>
        <p class="second_main_paragraph">Check out the gallery section to see which type of cupcake you prefer. If you don't see your favorite, you can contact us and give us suggestions on what other type of cupcakes we should offer. We take feedback seriously and want to provide the best cupcakes to our customers.</p>
        <a href="orders.html"><img src="images/contact-button.png" alt="contact_button" class="contact_button"></a>
        <img src="images/cupcake.png" alt="cupcake" class="cupcake">
    </article>
</section> <!-- end of section -->

<footer>
    <p>Taffie's Cupcakes &copy; copyright 2014</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="orders.html">orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer> <!-- end of footer -->

</div> <!-- end of container -->
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fijeqi/3/edit)**

```
footer ul{
  float:right; /* FLOAT RIGHT UL INSTEAD */
}
footer li{
  display:inline-block; /* needed */
}
footer ul li a{
  display:inline-block; /* needed in order to add padding. */
  padding: 10px;        /* Add some padding to your links, UX, remember? */
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#784f3d;
  /* margin:10px; Not needed, accounted it all to padding! */
  /* float:left;  Not needed */
}
footer ul li a:hover{
  color:#3d2316;
}
```